# Mysql Strange Double Out of Range Error

Tags: mysql

I have an Html form that let the user transfer stocks between two warehouses (From the main (decrease) to the sub (increase)).  But when the user submits the form from to the Server, a Mysql error rises up that the submitted value is out of range.  But when the user reloads the page and resubmit the same data again, it passes with no database error.

Can someone help me identify the underlying issue here?

Info:
Server OS: OPENSUSE LEAP 42.1
Client OS: WINDOWS 10 Pro x64
Database: Maria DB 10
Application Server: Apache
Server-Side Language: PHP
Main & Sub Columns Data Type: double (50,3)

Comment: Sounds like some sort of uninitialized variable in the php coding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i'm sure about the data types by using floatval () to all of the variables. So why it success from the second time !!

Comment: Hi all, could I find any answer